# Designing a data model for MongoDB

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb

I have a dataset in Mysql that contains movies , ratings and users that made these ratings on users. I really struggle to understand how I will construct my dataset from mysql schema in order to fit and get imported to mongo.I have extracted the dataset from mysql in json format so now I need to modify it for example embed the ratings into the movies. I would like to ask for some advice on how to do this. Is there any tool available or I should code something to extract from mysql and construct the json? Sorry for my noob question

Answer (score 0):

Way of storing data by MongoDB is nearly the same as JSON. Mongo doesn't force you to define any data model, so you can do just something like that:

```
db.yourcollection.insert(JSON.parse(yourJSONFile));
```

But of course there are many advantages of validating data. For these purposes I recommend SimpleSchema package.